# Subtracting one list of lists from another

Tags: list-manipulation

I have two lists of lists, like:

```
list1 = {{2}, {4}, {3, 1}, {2, 2}, {6}, {5, 1}, {4, 2}, {4, 2}, {8}, {7, 1}, 
{6, 2}, {6, 2}, {5, 3}, {4, 4}}
list2={{2, 2}, {4, 2}, {6, 2}, {4, 4}}
```

Note that, in list1, the partitions {4,2} and {6,2} occur twice.  In general, there could be more than 2 occurrences of a particular element of either list, and my partitions could have more than 2 parts.

I want to "subtract" the contents of list2 from list1 (i.e. count its occurrences negatively, and merge it with list1) so the final result is

```
list3= {{2}, {4}, {3, 1}, {6}, {5, 1}, {4, 2}, {8}, {7, 1}, {6, 2},  {5, 3}}
```

i.e. if a partition $(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_k)$ occurs $p_1(a)$ times in list1 and $q_1(a)$ times in list2, the result should be a list where $(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_k)$ occurs $p_1(a)-q_1(a)$ times.

"Complement" doesn't quite work here as it would eliminate {4,2} and {6,2} from list3.  Any help would be appreciated.

For context this come up when using modification rules for non-standard representations, which here are represented by partitions.  The modification rules produce partitions with negative coefficient which ``cancels out'' an appropriate number of like standard representations in some expansion: see for instance

> King RC. Modification rules and products of irreducible representations of the unitary, orthogonal, and symplectic groups. Journal of Mathematical Physics. 1971 Aug;12(8):1588-98.

Comment: `list3` should not contain `{2,2}`, right?

Comment: @kglr fixed.  Thanks.

Comment: you also need to remove `{4,4}` from `list3`?

Comment: @kglr yes as you can see removing manually from a long list is not very convenient...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**1.** [`Fold`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Fold.html) + [`DeleteCases`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DeleteCases.html)

```
Fold[DeleteCases[##, 1, 1] &, list1, list2]
```

> ```
> {{2}, {4}, {3, 1}, {6}, {5, 1}, {4, 2}, {8}, {7, 1}, {6, 2}, {5, 3}}
> ```

**2.** [`Counts`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Counts.html) + [`KeyUnion`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/KeyUnion.html) + [`KeyValueMap`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/KeyValueMap.html)

```
Join @@ KeyValueMap[ConstantArray][Subtract @@ KeyUnion[Counts /@ {list1, list2}, 0 &]]
```

> ```
> {{2}, {4}, {3, 1}, {6}, {5, 1}, {4, 2}, {8}, {7, 1}, {6, 2}, {5, 3}}
> ```

Alternatively,

```
KeyValueMap[Apply[Sequence]@*ConstantArray][
 Subtract @@ KeyUnion[Counts /@ {list1, list2}, 0 &]]
```

> ```
> {{2}, {4}, {3, 1}, {6}, {5, 1}, {4, 2}, {8}, {7, 1}, {6, 2}, {5, 3}}
> ```

Comment: The second option I understand better and works perfectly.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

```
Delete[list1,FirstPosition[list1, #]&/@list2]
```

> {{2}, {4}, {3, 1}, {6}, {5, 1}, {4, 2}, {8}, {7, 1}, {6, 2}, {5, 3}}

Comment: Nice!  This also works very well.